PHP Deprecated: Non-static method should not be called statically
Hello all i have an error log on my website that is drastically filling each day ( within a couple of months the error log is over 5gb)

PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Rules::getStickerData() should not be called statically in public_html/modules/productlabelsandstickers/productlabelsandstickers.php on line 777


PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Rules::getStickerData() should not be called statically in public_html/modules/productlabelsandstickers/productlabelsandstickers.php on line 901

Where both lines are:
$excluded_p = Rules::getStickerData($value['fmm_stickers_rules_id']);

Can anyone help rewrite this non statically for me?
Thanks,
Darcy
additional info:
The blocks from these lines of code with errors are as follows:
Error on line 777 where 777 is the 5th line down
 //Now check for brands rule existance
        $rule_brands = $rules->getAllApplicable('brand');
        foreach ($rule_brands as $key => $value) {
            $fmm_stickers_rules_id[] = $value['fmm_stickers_rules_id'];
            $excluded_p = Rules::getStickerData($value['fmm_stickers_rules_id']);
            $excluded_p = explode(',', $excluded_p);

            $inarr = in_array($id, $excluded_p);
           if ($inarr) {
               unset($rule_brands[$key]);
            }
       }

Error on line 901 where 901 is the 6th line down)
 //Check for Out of Stock status
        if ($check_stock <= 0) {
            $rule_oos = $rules->getAllApplicable('outofstock');
            foreach ($rule_oos as $key => $value) {
                $fmm_stickers_rules_id[] = $value['fmm_stickers_rules_id'];
                $excluded_p = Rules::getStickerData($value['fmm_stickers_rules_id']);
                $excluded_p = explode(',', $excluded_p);

                $inarr = in_array($id, $excluded_p);
                
                if ($inarr) {
                    unset($rule_oos[$key]);
                }
            }
            if (count($rule_oos) > 0) {
                foreach ($rule_oos as $stick) {
                    array_push($stickers_pro, $object->getSticker($stick['sticker_id'], $type));
                }
            }
        }

edit
The code where rules is defined is here from what i can see, Sorry i'm not the best with coding or understanding pretty new to it all:
public function getStickerData($id)
{
    $result = Db::getInstance()->getValue('
    SELECT `excluded_p`
    FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'fmm_stickers_rules`
    WHERE `fmm_stickers_rules_id` = ' . (int) $id);
    return $result;
}


We can't rewrite this from what you've posted here. The problem is in the Rulesclass, where the method has not been declared as astaticmethod. Either you need to change the declaration in theRulesclass, or you need to instantiate theRules` class and use the object to make the call non-statically.  There's not enough code here to determine what to do.

As the previous comment suggests, the function is already not static. We'd need to see the definition of that function. Update the question with the function definition, do not add as another comment in this area.

Thanks for the reply, Ill update the above with the whole code from this document in case i miss anything else the definition is:
' $rules = new Rules(); '
So i am assuming i need to reqrite it something like:
' $excluded_p = $rules_instance->getStickerData($value['fmm_stickers_rules_id']);
$excluded_p = explode(',', $excluded_p); '

No, don't add the whole code. Add enough that you can understand the solution, then you can modify the rest of the code yourself. See "[mcve]"

Thanks for the reply, i have updated the main post with the definition of rules sorry i'm new to all this

"The code where rules is defined is here"... that's not the method in question. You need to show the getStickerData method from the Rules class. There's a good chance you just need to label it as static using the static keyword

Thanks for the response! have updated with the getStickerData method

Simply change it to public static function getStickerData($id)

So simply change that line from
"public function getStickerData($id)"
to
"public static function getStickerData($id)"
is that correct?

That's right. This is assuming you want it to be static. If it shouldn't be static, then instead you should update the code which calls that function (where the error message originated) to use an instance of the class instead. That's a design decision you need to make -we can't tell you how to design your application and your models, we can only tell you about the technical problem which is causing the error. I would say though that there's nothing in the internal code of getStickerData which would cause me to be concerned about making it into a static function.

Excellent thanks so much for your help, i updated it and no more error log happening. Thanks all for your help and patience with me, greatly appreciated
